# Android - dynamically update GridView views

Tags: android, gridview

I've got a GridView with a custom Adapter, displaying thumbnails of pictures to the user. I can select and deselect pictures (I use setAlpha(0.25) on the views to notify the user of the change), and that's all well and fine.

Now what I want to do next, is have a button on top of the gridview that clears the whole selection, i.e. call setAlpha(1.0) on all views that were changed. So far I can reset my elements in the adapter, and I can setAlpha to 1, but the view doesn't update unless I scroll it out of the display, and then get back to it, or notify the adapter of changes, which redraws all my views, which does not look too pretty if only one element was selected.

I already dynamically set and reset individual elements through the GridView's onClickListener, but can't do this for more. I even tried calling performClick on all selected items through my button, but again it only displays the changes after the views have been out of the screen and are shown again.

Here's how I simulate the clicks:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    PictureForSelection tempPic = (PictureForSelection) mAdapter.getItem(i);

    if (tempPic.isPicSelected()) {
            //tempPic.setIfSelected(false);

            gridview.performItemClick(mAdapter.getView(i, null, null), i, i);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Conclusion - don't simulate clicks like this :)

So now I skip click simulation and use this:

```
gridview.getChildAt(i).setAlpha((float) 1.0);
```

In general it does exactly what I wanted it to do, except for one case:

- If I have for example 3 pictures selected, one is off screen, one is partly shown, and one is fully shown, the ones shown (even partially) don't update their views.

If all the selected pictures are displayed it works flawlessly, but if some are out of the display, the rest do not update until the adapter's getView() gets called by Android. Still, thanks @mmlooloo for getting me so far.

If anyone knows a way around this, please do share :)

Comment: Dose `mAdapter.getView(i, null, null)` return any view? you pass the parent and convertView null??

Comment: Yes, that was a bit of a problem... Took me a while to get what you meant by getting the children, updating the post in a second :)

Answer (score 0):

After setting your alpha you can call `imageview.invalidate();` this causes your `imageview` to redraw itself.

Comment: Thanks, tried it but the behaviour remained the same. From the separate button I call performClick(), setAlpha() and invalidate on the item view, but again it changes only after it has been out of the display. By the way, the docs say invalidate() would cause onDraw() to be called.. do I have to implement an onDraw()? I was hoping invalidate to cause the adapter's getView() to be called, but whatever works :)

Comment: No you do not need to override the onDraw(). you can try calling invalidate for child view. for example get child view from the adapter and then call invalidate for that view.

Comment: Yes, I added it to the code but nothing changed. When Android itself calls onClick(), everything is fine even without invalidate. But when I call it, the values in the adapter change, but the view remains the same until getView gets called by Android. I'm starting to think something is wrong with my logic of simulating click events, think I'd better update my post...

Answer (score 0):

if notifyDataSetChanged() is not working you can try like this. 
i'm not sure whether this works,

1.onclick of the button you set the gridView.setAdapter(null);
2. Then set a new CustomAdapter object  to gridview with default values.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is not that notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't work, but that it makes all my items redraw themselves, and what I'd like to get is only the modified items to redraw themselves.